# rethrow_if_nested possible implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, std

[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/rethrow_if_nested) provides some details on `rethrow_if_nested` possible implementation. These details are of interest to me. While most of the expressions seem reasonable to me, the definition of `can_dynamic_cast` is a little bit confusing:

```
    template <class E>
    struct can_dynamic_cast
        : std::integral_constant<bool,
              std::is_polymorphic<E>::value &&
              (!std::is_base_of<std::nested_exception, E>::value ||
                std::is_convertible<E*, std::nested_exception*>::value)
          > { };
```

I can't imagine a situation where `(!std::is_base_of<std::nested_exception, E>::value || std::is_convertible<E*, std::nested_exception*>::value)` evaluation at compile time results into `false`. To be more specific,

- if `std::is_base_of<std::nested_exception, E>::value == false`, then
  `!std::is_base_of<std::nested_exception, E>::value == true`
- if `std::is_base_of<std::nested_exception, E>::value == true`, then
  type `E` is derived from `std::nested_exception` and we can cast `E*` into `std::nested_exception*` anyway.

So, the question is what is wrong with my discussion, and why `can_dynamic_cast` shall be implemented this way?

NB: As far as I can see, GCC 7 implements the logic above. At the same time, LLVM's implementation seems to check that the type of the argument is polymorphic, and nothing else:

```
template <class _Ep>                                                            
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY                                                
void                                                                            
rethrow_if_nested(const _Ep& __e, typename enable_if<                           
                                  is_polymorphic<_Ep>::value                   
                                                    >::type* = 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `std::nested_exception` is an ambiguous or inaccessible base of `E` (e.g. `E` privately inherits from `std::nested_exception`), `std::is_base_of<std::nested_exception, E>::value` is true, but `E*` is not convertible to `std::nested_exception*`.